# SQLAlchemy order_by string column with int values

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy, lexicographic

I have a table with a String column but it holds only integers (as strings).

Problem comes when I want to order_by this column on certain query. SQLAlchemy (or python more specifically) uses lexicographic order for strings, so

```
>>> '100000' < '99999'
True
```

even when

```
>>> 100000 < 99999
False
```

How can I achieve to order_by a numerical value of this string column?

I currently have a query such as this:

```
session.query(TableName).filter(TableName.column == 'some_value').order_by(TableName.string_column_holding_integers).all()
```

Please mind that changing the type of the column to an integer is not an option, I need to order_by correctly (by numerical value) on the present conditions.

Also just found that directly on the DB using SQL (this one is a MySQL DB) I cannot order by this column correctly, so I found that using a CAST(string_column_holding_integers AS unsigned) works here. But haven't found a way to do this one (the CAST part) directly on SQLAlchemy queries.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do a [`cast`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast) in SQLAlchemy like this:

```
session.query(...).filter(...).order_by(cast(TableName.string_column_holding_integers, Integer))
```

Comment: what if the column contains both numbers & strings ? how can I still preserve a correct ordering ?

Comment: @Ricky That's not possible. All values in a column must be the same type.

Comment: In PostgressSQL i.e you can do: ORDER BY NULLIF(regexp_replace(my_column_1, E'\\D', '', 'g'), '')::int ( if the value is not INT - it ignores and continue ) this way we can order numeric values correctly and continue with strings as usual, que is - how in SQLAlchemy we do it

Comment: @Ricky That's not a mixed-type column, as you put it, but you can order by the same thing. You can even use that exact string if you wanted to by using `text`. Try `.order_by(cast(func.nullif(func.regexp_replace(tbl.c.my_column_1, "\\D", "", "g"), ""), Integer))`.

Comment: Thank you ! that's what I was looking for ! ;-)

Comment: for me, the alphanumeric sort I was looking for was `.order_by(cast(func.substring(Tbl.name, "([0-9]+)"), DECIMAL).asc(), Tbl.name)`

Answer (score 1):

The best approach I could come up with for Alphanumeric was this:

```
from sqlalchemy import DECIMAL, cast, func

session.query(...).filter(...).order_by(
        func.ascii(TableName.column_name).asc(),
        cast(
            func.nullif(func.regexp_replace(TableName.column_name, "\\D", "", "g"), ""),
            DECIMAL,
        ).asc(),
    )
```

Which sorts things like:

```
-----+-------------
 1   
 100 
 2   
 20  
 A1  
 A2  
 B1
```

Not perfect (ideally, 100 would be after 20 ...). I hope the community can help me answer this better someday.